# No Testng reports coming in Email with jenkins Email Ext Plugin

Tags: jenkins

My expectation is to receive a mail with TestNg report in it, either as attachment or in body.I have below configuration in jenkins but after running job it is saying "No emails were triggered."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8DCs.png)

so please help me on how to get a email with testng report.
Thanks in advance

Comment: complete path of emailable report is "/var/nyt/jenkins-slave/workspace/aristo/aristo-jenkinsTest/target/results/emailable-report.html"

Comment: Try using `aristo/aristo-jenkinsTest/target/results/emailable-report.html` in Attachments field. (Note the comment: The base directory is the workspace.)

Comment: Can you share the job failure/success log where you see that " job it is saying "No emails were triggered.""

Comment: Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:17 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-24T02:58:49-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 102M/1381M
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
No emails were triggered.
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: @Edvins I made following changes Default content :${FILE path=”aristo/aristo-jenkinsTest/target/results/emailable-report.html”} Attachments:aristo/aristo-jenkinsTest/target/results/emailable-report.html but still i see the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to define appropriate triggers for email notification.

Click the button *Advanced Settings...* to access the list of defined triggers.

Then select *Add Trigger* -> *Always* to send notifications after each build.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not configured / Add **Recipient List** in Trigger section.

- Click on **Advanced settings...** at bottom of right side.
- Click on **Add** dropdown of Triggers's success block and select **Recipient List** from that.
- Apply and save your configuration.

[image]

**NOTE**

Make sure your default triggers in global configuration is checked success.

- For that you have to go to **Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Extended E-mail Notification.**
- Click on Default Triggers at bottom right corner and checkmark on success option.

*This configuration send mail only when your build is success. If you want to allow send mail always, then you have to choose always option in default trigger.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Manage Jenkins ---> Configure System ---> Email Notification`

```
set smtp to : smtp.gmail.com
```

click on advanced

select `use smtp authentication`
enter email and password from which you want to send email,

> note- you need to enable the settings for the particular email id to
>   allow the third party software to send mails in gmail settings.

```
use ssh - tick.
smtp port - 465.
```

after that in job config set trigger as mentioned in other answers